# Universal Windows Platform - Backward compatibility and Windows 10 versions

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have started to explore the *Universal Windows Platform*, and saw at the [Windows 10 SDK download page:](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

> The Windows 10 SDK allows you to build Universal Windows apps as well as desktop apps for Windows 10, version 1607.

If I build an app with this SDK, will it work on future versions of Windows 10?

This is from the page that lists all [Windows 10 version 1607 API changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-version-1607-api-diff):

> Many runtime APIs have been added or changed in Windows 10 version 1607. This table lists the namespaces that have been added or changed in this release. [...]

When browsing the classes, you can see notices regarding this. For ex., several members of the class [`Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer) have this notice:

> MediaPlayer.[MemberName] may be altered or unavailable after Windows 10, version 1607. Instead, use [...]

So I don't get it. No more backward compatibility? If I build an app for version 1607, may it break after the user update Windows 10 to the next version? Or will it work, but my code become "obsolete"?

Comment: Agile development is the new religion at Microsoft.  Only way to stay competitive with the Googles.  So lots of incremental releases, constant change, lots of bugs.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm curious, as you say MS is following Google being agile, is google API and SDK buggy like MS as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it as making an app for Android: Your app can work as long as Google doesn't break the interface. Usually when they change something, they give you time (by the message kind of "MediaPlayer.[MemberName] may be altered or unavailable after Windows 10, version 1607. Instead, use [...]") to update your app.

UWP app for Windows 10 is no different in that scene.

> If I build an app with this SDK, will it work on future versions of Windows 10?

Yes. If it will not work, then they will tell you explicitly that it won't work in version xxxx. Now they are using the word `May be`.